# Laravel relationship similar to belongsToThrough()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I'm using Laravel 8. I would like to access data from Table C to Table A, through Table B with only 1 query.

Let's say I have the following tables:

A) Pages 
B) Posts 
C) Comments

How can I get the Page of a Comment if I only have the Post ID in the Comments table with 1 Query?

This is what I currently have:

**Comments Model:**

```
public function post()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comments', 'post_id');
}
```

**Posts Model:**

```
public function page()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pages', 'page_id');
}
```

...and I'm trying to access the `Page` from `Comments` like this:

```
Comments::with('post.page')->get();
```

While this is working fine, Laravel is executing 3 queries here instead of the 1 that I would need. What am I missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6161

Comment: Laravel will always make separate queries if you use `with` because this is most efficient. You could do something like `Comments::where('post_id', $post_id)->join('posts', 'posts.id', 'comments.post_id')->get()` to make it 1 query. But please notice that 1 query is not per definition better than multiple queries.

Comment: @RobBiermann Ah I see, I thought one query is going to have better performance. It makes sense. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll keep it in mind!